# NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;) while executing tests through CLI with ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a TestNG test that works as expected when run as TestNG Suite in Eclipse, but fails when run via command line. I see the issue it cannot launch the browser but classpath setting is working correctly as i just printed helloworl without webdriver code.Can anyone help me what i'm missing here

```
package testngex;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login {

    @Test

    public void main() {

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //Implicit wait
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           driver.get("url");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys("xxx");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("xxx);
        driver.findElement(By.id("imgbtnLogin")).click();
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
 <suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="testngex.Login"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Error Test

```
testngex.Login#main
```

> ```
> Exception
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:125)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:156)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:346)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:91)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>   at testngex.Login.main(Login.java:17)
> ... Removed 24 stack frames
> ```

Comment: Please post the error for failure. Thanks

Comment: i see it fails at this point WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

Answer (score 1):

Use Maven Surefire Plugin. And use pattern to make it identify your test classes like so...

```
mvn -Dtest=test* test
```

Comment: How will use of Maven solve the OP's problem with NoSuchMethodError? Also: are you sure that using "-Dtest=test*" will make Surefire identify your tests classes?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

...implies that the **JVM** was unable to locate the necessary **WebDriver** variant i.e. **ChromeDriver** to initiate a new session.

Your main issue is, you haven't mentioned the location of **ChromeDriver** to **JVM**. Hence the error.

### Solution

Add the `System.setProperty()` line at the begining of your code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: @Debanjan- added code but still same issue. Everything works fine if run in eclipse but test fails if i run from command prompt.